# jQuery Select2 plugin on dynamicaly loaded div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I try to load a div that has a listbox with a select2 plugin.
The below code is for the div container

```
<div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo lang('project_product', 'product', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select id="id_product" name="id_product" tabindex="4" class="form-control select2 id_product"></select> 
        </div>
    </div>       

    <div class="form-actions pull-right">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="cancel_product" class="btn btn-default">
            Cancel
        </a>&nbsp; 
        <a href="javascript:;" id="add" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add product
        </a>            
    </div> 
</div>
```

The div container is loaded by a on click event on a button:

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_product', function(e){
    $('#add_p_container').removeClass('hide');
    $('#add_p_container').load(JS_BASE_URL + 'admin/projects/add_product/' + id_project);       
});
```

The issue is that, if I load the jQuery from below in the js file where the on click event for the `#add_product`, nothing will work for the select2.

The code that I use to initialize the select2:

```
$("#id_product").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2,
    placeholder: "Select a product",
    allowClear: true,
    quietMillis: 100,
    ajax: {
        url: JS_BASE_URL + 'admin/products/productsList',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "GET",
        quietMillis: 50,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          // parse the results into the format expected by Select2
          // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
          // alter the remote JSON data, except to indicate that infinite
          // scrolling can be used
          params.page = params.page || 1;

          return {
            results: data,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
          };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
        return markup;
    } // let our custom formatter work

});
```

If I load the select2 from above directly when loading it in the div, I will receive the error:

```
 [Show/hide message details.] SyntaxError: expected property name, got end of script
```

Does any of you know how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After trying to search a way to fix the issue, it seems that loading the script into the div will work but removing all the comments
I don't know why, but it des work

So, make sure you do not leave any comments, otherways it will not work